vmware workstation - add hardware when suspended
I am using vmware workstation pro.
When judging by the common sense,
the stability of the state of a virtual machine can be compared as follows :
powered off : most stable
suspended : fairly stable
going on(=powered on and not suspended) : least stable
But we can add hardware when a virtual machine is
powered off, or going on.
(Hardware tab)

(hardware add activated)

(hardware add de-activated)

For example, it is impossible to add a new hdd when it is suspended, but it is possible to add a new hdd when it is going on.
For my common sense, suspended state is more stable than going-on state. So if adding hardware is possible in the going-on state, it should also be possible in the suspended state.
What part am I thinking wrong? (or do you agree it is a little strange ?)

Questions seeking if we agree or not don’t typically do well on Super User, far to many, opinions without any experience usually. I find the stability to be equal among all 3 states in my personal experience using ESXi for over 10 years

This question could just be slightly rephrased to "Why does it behave this way?" instead of "Do you agree with this behavior?".

Some virtual devices can be added while a VM is powered on if the guest OS supports hot-plug operations for those devices.  The VM needs to be running to initiate a hot-plug event, and it needs to be running so that the VMware Workstation UI can query VMware Tools in the guest to determine if hot-plugging is even allowed.
That's not possible if the VM isn't running.
In general, you cannot modify a VM while it is suspended.  Doing so basically means changing the state of the virtual hardware from under the guest OS, which would terribly confuse the guest OS and probably lead to guest memory corruption or other undefined behavior in the guest.

I couldn't possibly guess why. Thank you for the clear answer!
